# How to display current value to input field

Tags: angular, forms, ngmodel

I have a table, where is list of input's from:

```
 list=[
{id:1,value:null},
{id:2, value:null},
]
```

I am using input fields to change the value of each object from a list and send the data to one database

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of list">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>
           <input matInput type="number"name="fname" [(ngModel)]="item.value">
        </td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

After that I am getting data from the database and want to display the current value from the database. The problem is I am sending data ok, getting data ok but the current data is not showing in the input field. When I use [(value)] instead of [(ngModel)], the data from the database is displayed fine, but I can no longer send the value.

Comment: Hi, I can only speculate as to why it's not working properly for you.
 Can you take the time to upload a stackblitz sample?

Comment: take account that, when you get the data from database, you need change the value of "list", INSIDE the function subscribe

Comment: yes i do that and as i say it works with [(value)] instead of [(ngModel)], but in this case I cannot send data anymore because "list" is not getting values from input

Answer (score 0):

value is a property you can bind a value to with [value]="name" while (valueChange)="..." doesn't work, because the  element doesn't have an @Output() valueChange; therefore [(value)]="..." is invalid

Answer (score 0):

See : **[StackblitzDemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ho26tz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

in case your request take too long so data will not shown in your view directly after component init so u need to use

1 - **[ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)**

2 - **[async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)** for view and it was the best for it

Comment: The problem is that I have an initial table with a start data that the user sees, and then when the data is inserted into the database and returned, I need to have the same initial table with the update data from the database. If I use for example if (element.id == 1) and set a value for an object where id is 1, the object in the table is updated, but its value is not displayed in the input field. If I assign a value from all objects without an if condition, the value is displayed in the input field. I don't need to rewrite initial table with data from base.

Comment: the problem was i used the same id for all input fields:)